# How to reference assets by filepath in npm package? (application: webworker)

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, web-worker

I've written and published a vanilla JS node package, with the following package.json:

```
{
  "name": "...",
  "description": "...",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "types": "./index.d.ts",
  "main": "./dist/bundle.js",
...
}
```

I'm also using webpack, with the following webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const WebpackShellPlugin = require('webpack-shell-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/js/main.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        library: '',
        libraryTarget: 'commonjs-module'
    },
    plugins: [
        new WebpackShellPlugin({onBuildStart:['rm -r dist', 'mkdir dist']})
    ]
};
```

Finally, I'm using the worker-loader in my library in the following way:

```
var MyWorker = require('worker-loader!./workers/worker.js');
...
var worker = new MyWorker();
```

When I run webpack, it compiles without issue and places `bundle.js` and `c6...[hash code].worker.js` in `dist/`. So I publish the package this way.

Now when I try to include the library in a different, typescript/babel/es6 project with `import MyClass from 'packagename'`, everything works well, RIGHT UNTIL we get to the line in the library:

```
var worker = new MyWorker();
```

At which point the browser gives a 404 error that it couldn't find `localhost:8080/c6...[hash code].worker.js`.

Does anyone know how to deal with this? I've confirmed that the file `c6...[hash code].worker.js` is in `node_modules/packagename/dist`